# FingerPrint authentication or Biometric authentication code sample using nativescript for android

Tags: nativescript

I need code guidelines or sample for Biometric or FingerPrint/FaceId authentication using native-script for Android.

Native-Script

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for [nativescript-fingerprint-auth](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-fingerprint-auth) plugin, the plugin [repo](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-fingerprint-auth/tree/master/demo) includes demo apps too.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-fingerprint-auth
```